# What's the meanning of the options of linux command `uname`?

Tags: linux, uname

From man uname:

```
   -a, --all
          print all information [...]
   -m, --machine
          print the machine hardware name
   -p, --processor
          print the processor type or "unknown"
   -i, --hardware-platform
          print the hardware platform or "unknown"
```

in my computer:

```
[liwm29@VM-12-11-centos bc_sns]$ uname -p
x86_64
[liwm29@VM-12-11-centos bc_sns]$ uname -m
x86_64
[liwm29@VM-12-11-centos bc_sns]$ uname -i
x86_64
```

I don't know the difference between them

Comment: Use  a different hardware platform, and you'll get different results. If you have an Android Phone, you can install the "Termux" App and then run the commands there.

Comment: uname -a : All information in one line. -m is the OS, reply is e.g. i686 or x86_64. -p and -i is for hardware specs.